# Specify makeinfo to be used in make command

Tags: makefile, osx-yosemite, texinfo

On OS X Yosemite, the standart texinfo version is quite old and does not suppprt certain features.

I now have installed, via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), a newer version. As there is an already existing version, the binaries are not put into the PATH (keg only), which makes perfect sense.

Now, how can I tell `make`, **without modifying the make file** that I want to use the binary located at `/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/makeinfo`?

I could

1. link makeinfo in the PATH
2. execute make
3. unlink texinfo

But I consider this un-elegant.

Is this my only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your makefile.  If it uses a variable to hold the name of the makeinfo program, something like this:

```
MAKEINFO = /usr/bin/makeinfo

foo.info: foo.texi
       $(MAKEINFO) ...
```

then you can simply run `make MAKEINFO=/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/makeinfo`.

Alternatively, if it uses just the name of the program without a path, like `makeinfo`, you can set your `$PATH` variable before invoking make: `PATH=/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin:$PATH make`

If your makefile invokes `makeinfo` using a hardcoded path with no variable:

```
foo.info: foo.texi
        /usr/bin/makeinfo ...
```

then you're out of luck and you *HAVE TO* change your makefile.

Comment: Thanks. It uses ```MAKEINFO = makeinfo``` so I can use the first or the last approach.